# Would the Nikon TC14E II teleconverter work with a Tamron 70-200mm f/2.8?

Tags: lens-adapter, telephoto, micro-four-thirds, teleconverter, adapter

I mostly do photography using Nikon gear. When it comes to video I use the Panasonic GH5 and adapt my Nikon lenses via adapter. The adapter does not have any electronics. So I'm stuck to manual focus (which is perfectly fine) and also I can't change the aperture of the Tamron 70-200mm G2 since it has an electronic aperture.

When I use the Tamron 70-200 f/2.8 on this body it gives me an equivalent of an 140-400mm f/2.8 (which is awesome!). However I'm thinking whether I should get the Nikon TC14E II teleconverter for my photography stuff. I came across the question if this teleconverter would work on my Tamron 70-200mm without any controls just for the extra reach. I know that Nikon's TCs are only made for a couple of Nikon lenses and they might not work with the Tamron lens **on my Nikon body** - but **would they work on the GH5?**

Remember, I don't need any autofocus, vibration reduction or aperture control to work since the camera can't communicate to the lens anyway. I just would need to this a manual lens with more reach.

Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

The TC compatibility is not about the camera body, but is mostly about the camera lens. The danger is that the rear glass element of the lens could project out to touch and be damaged by the front element of the teleconverter when connected together.

FWIW, here is [Nikons list of compatibility](https://cdn-5.nikon-cdn.com/Assets/Common-Assets/Images/Teleconverter-Compatibility/EN_Comp_chart.html) with their lenses.

Auto focus compatibility could be about the body model.  [Another Nikon article](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/using-teleconverters.html) addresses TC auto focus issues.

Answer (score 0):

A lens+TC is just a lens form the camera body perspective, so if your lens+TC work on your Nikon they will (optically and mechanically) work on your GH5. So the question is whether the Nikon TC and a Tamron lens can work together.

Few people seems to use a Nikon TC with a Tamron lens, they are mostly doing the opposite, a Tamron TC added on a Nikon lens, so if you intend to use the TC mostly with the Tamron lens, a Tamron TC would be less expensive and work just as well.

Comment: Yep. Thats true. I plan to use the TC ob multiple Nikon lenses. A Tamron TC would not pay off for me. If the Nikon TC would work mechanically and optically with the Tamron it just would be a reason to got for it now instead of later on this year because I could take advantage of this combo right now. Could anybody try the Nikon TC on the Tamron G2 70-200mm?